# Access callback called multiple times?

Tags: 7, routes

I have this hook_menu implementation

```
$items['lablab/%level/%unit/%tab/%section/%exercise/go'] = array(
        'title'           => 'My lablab',
        'title callback'  => 'lablab_form_set_title',
        'page callback'   => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'  => array('lablab_form',1, 2, 3, 4 ,5),
        'access callback' => 'lablab_access_exercise',
        'access arguments' => array(5),
        'file'            => 'lablab.forms.inc',
        'file path'       => drupal_get_path('module', 'lablab').'/includes',
        'type'            => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
```

And then in the access callback

```
function lablab_access_exercise($w_exercise){
    dpm($w_exercise->value());
}
```

Then when i enter the hook_menu page it shows me at least 4 dpms, is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

the wildcard %exercise was returning several entities.